# Resetting VueJS data properties to initial values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component that is provided an initial data property via a passed-in component `prop` and stored in a data variable:

```
<component :propvar="true"></component>

data() {
  return {
    localvar: this.propvar,
    localvar2: true
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to revert the data variable back to this prop's value when hitting a 'reset' button with a method like this:

```
methods: {
  reset() {
    Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data());
  }
}
```

The problem is that the data variable is `undefined` when referencing the prop's value via `this.options.data()`:

`console.log(this.$options.data()); => Object {localvar: undefined, localvar2: true}`

[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fjpqz387/48/)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you really need to reset all of your data properties by firing the `data()` method again, you can do that like so:

```
methods: {
  reset() {
    Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data.call(this));
  }
}
```

The `this` variable in the `this.$options.data` is referencing the options, not the vue component instance. That's why the `localvar` property was `undefined`. So if you're calling it from the vue instance, you'll need to give it a reference to `this` via the function's [`call()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

---

But, in most circumstances, I would just assign the value directly instead of calling `Object.assign`:

```
methods: {
  reset() {
    this.localvar = this.propvar;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice!  That seems to do the trick.  Just for clarification:  the reason why I would prefer to use `Object.assign()` in this instance is because it is a lot cleaner when you have many props (which I do for this particular component - not shown in the example). Just as you stated, under most circumstances, the other method would be just fine . Thank you!